# Matching (and binding) two exception classes in one case statement in Scala 2.7?

Tags: scala, syntax, exception, case

I have the following code:

```
try {
    < ... some JSON parsing code .. >
} 
catch {
    case e:ClassCastException => throw new ParseException(body, e)
    case e:JSONException => throw new ParseException(body, e)
}
```

This seems overly repetitious. I tried

```
case e:ClassCastException | e:JSONException => throw new ParseException(body, e)
```

but Scala won't let me bind `e` to both types - fair enough. In the handler, I only need to treat `e` as if it were of type `Exception`, but I only want to match in the first place if it's one of those specific classes. Something like having a condition after the matched type, like:

```
case e:Exception(ClassCastException|JSONException) => throw new ParseException(body, e)
```

That's obviously not the right syntax, but hopefully you see what I mean. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't introduce bindings inside of Pattern Alternatives (`PatternA | PatternB`). But you can bind a name to the result of Pattern Alternatives with a Pattern Binder (`name @ Pattern`).

```
try {
    < ... some JSON parsing code .. >
} catch {
    case e @ (_: ClassCastException | _: JSONException) => throw new ParseException(body, e)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the new 2.8 control constructs:

```
def foo = //JSON parsing code

import util.control.Exception._
handling(classOf[ClassCastException], classOf[JSONException]) by (t => throw new ParseException(t)) apply foo
```

(There's probably a mistake in there. I can't find an [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) for the jabscreen.)

Comment: It's not quite the Ruby one, is it?

Comment: good answer, although I'm stuck on 2.7 for now - which I should have specified; I've update the question to reflect that now.

Comment: You could actually back-port util.control.Exception to 2.7. I don't think it relies on new language features.